# Remove all lines starting with a lower case character

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

How to remove all lines from a file if they begin with a lower case character or punctuation?

```
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
a banana .
aban Bajramovi was a Serbian-Romani musician.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
! a ban is the strictest punishment.
```

I would like my output to simply be:

```
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
```

I'm trying sed

```
sed 's/^[A-Z]/d' input
```

But not getting desired results, any tips?

Comment: Do you really want to REMOVE all lines that start with a lower case letter or punctuation, or is it more accurate (given your attempted solution) to say that you want to SELECT all lines that start with an upper case letter? What if a line started with a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/^[a-z[:punct:]]/d' file
```

or you can use character class for both as suggested by [@glennjackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491064/remove-all-lines-starting-with-a-lower-case-character#comment34217124_22491101) in comments:

```
sed '/^[[:lower:][:punct:]]/d' file
```

```
$ cat file
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
a banana .
aban Bajramovi was a Serbian-Romani musician.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
! a ban is the strictest punishment.
```

```
$ sed '/^[a-z[:punct:]]/d' file
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
```

```
$ sed '/^[[:lower:][:punct:]]/d' file
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
```

Comment: Might as well jump in with both feet then: `[[:lower:][:punct:]]`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. I forgot what `[a-z]` were classified as, so went with `[a-z]`. Will add that to the answer as reference. Thanks again! `:)`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Character-Class-Operators.html#Character-Class-Operators

Comment: Indeed, [a-z] and [A-Z] are unreliable because they'll give a different outcome for different locale...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex that targets the line you want to *omit*, then use grep's `-v` flag to return everything *else*:

```
grep -v '^[a-z[:punct:]]' < input
```

Comment: Still needs to handle punctuation! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really looking for is:

```
$ grep '^[[:upper:]]' file
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '!/^[[:lower:][:punct:]]/' file
A bamboo forest is located towards the ruins.
Abancay is a city in southern-central Peru.
```

Comment: or `awk '/^[[:upper:]]/' file` `:)`

Comment: @jaypal I did thought about that too, but then I see that number is not mention, so using `upper` will fail if line starts with a number.  It should `not` start with `lower` and `punctuation`...