# Bash Filtering strings with other than alphanumeric symbols

Tags: bash, sh

I have this line in my script

```
find $DIR -type f \( -iname "*.*" ! -iname ".*" \) | awk -F. '{print $NF}' | sort -u
```

And it bassicaly just finds every non-hidden files and prints its extension one per line, then sorts for duplicates, so an output could be for example:

```
exe 
c
x
png
lg_CNG
new
lib-old
s
```

I made that up, it should be in alphabetical order as well, but my question is can I somehow exclude those having any non-alphabetical symbol in them (_,-,/,.....)? Thank you

Comment: Find some inspiration here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491064/remove-all-lines-starting-with-a-lower-case-character

Comment: @FredrikPihl I tried and adding `| sed '/^[[:alnum:]]/d'` doesn't seem to work in my case, it doesn't print anything at all

Comment: Don't know what input you are running your `sed` on but `sed '/[[:punct:]]/d'` seems to work for me. In your output `lg_CNG` and `lib_old` is removed. That is expected, right?

Comment: This `^[[:alnum:]]` means _anything starting with a alphanumerical char_ so sed deletes them all.

Comment: @FredrikPihl yes, I see. Is `| sed '/^[[:alnum:]]*$/!d' ` the opposite then? And shoul it work, because it does it seems.

Comment: @zezollo oh, I see, thanks

Comment: Well, if you run the `sed` on the output of `ls` it will fail since all files contains punctuation if an extension is available. Parse out the filename first (`${line%.*}`) and then run the `sed` on that. Let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little change to your origin command, it works for me:

```
find . -type f -iname '*' ! -iname '.*' | sed -r -e '/[-_]/d' | awk -F'.' '{ print $NF }' | sort -u
```